# Missing page numbers

Tags: r, latex

I have the following YAML for a R Markdown file and I'm having trouble with the page numbering. I tried without the fancyhdr statements and it does not work either. I'd appreciate some help in finding out what's suppressing the page numbers.

```
---
title: " "
output: 
  pdf_document:
    number_sections: true
fontsize: 12pt
geometry: "left = 3cm, right = 2cm, top = 3cm, bottom = 2cm"
header-includes: 
  - \usepackage{booktabs}
  - \usepackage[portuguese]{babel}
  - \usepackage{tikz}
  - \usepackage{pgfplots}
  - \usepackage{float}
  - \usepackage{sectsty}
  - \usepackage{paralist}
  - \usepackage{setspace}\spacing{1.5}
  - \usepackage{fancyhdr}
  - \usepackage{lastpage}
  - \usepackage{dcolumn}
  - \usepackage{natbib}\bibliographystyle{agsm}
  - \usepackage[nottoc, numbib]{tocbibind}
  - \usepackage{xcolor, soul}
  - \sethlcolor{green}
  - \usepackage{fancyhdr}
  - \pagestyle{fancy} 
  - \pagenumbering{arabic}
  - \fancyhf{}
  - \fancyhead[L]{\thepage}
---
```

Comment: Try adding after `\pagestyle{fancy}`  this line  `\renewcommand{\headrulewidth}{0pt}` and check.